# regular expression for segmentation - splitting words into morphemes or affixes

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to get a list after segmenting a word into it's constituents such as suffixes and prefixes (i.e. morphemes or affixes).

I have tried using regular expressions, with the `re.findall` function.
(Shown below)

```
>>> import re
>>> affixes = ['meth','eth','ketone', 'di', 'chloro', 'yl', 'ol']
>>> word = 'dimethylamin0ethanol'
>>> re.findall('|'.join(affixes), word)

['di', 'meth', 'yl', 'eth', 'ol']
```

However, I need the sections in which it does not match to be included. For instance, the above example would be desired to output:

`['di', 'meth', 'yl', 'amin0', 'eth', 'an', 'ol']`

Does anyone know how to extract these segments in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) capturing the "delimiters":

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: affixes = ['meth', 'eth', 'ketone', 'di', 'chloro', 'yl', 'ol']

In [3]: word = 'dimethylamin0ethanol'

In [4]: [match for match in re.split('(' + '|'.join(affixes) + ')', word) if match]
Out[4]: ['di', 'meth', 'yl', 'amin0', 'eth', 'an', 'ol']
```

The list comprehension here is to filter the empty string matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

affixes = ['meth','eth','ketone', 'di', 'chloro', 'yl', 'ol']
word = 'dimethylamin0ethanol'

# found = ['amin0', 'an', 'di', 'meth', 'yl', 'eth', 'ol']
found = re.findall('|'.join(affixes), word)

# not_found = [('', 'di'), ('', 'meth'), ('', 'yl'), ('amin0', 'eth'), ('an', 'ol')] 
not_found = re.findall(r'(.*?)(' + '|'.join(affixes) + ')', word)

# We need to modify extract the first item out of each tuple in not_found 
# ONLY when it does not equal "".
all_items = map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[0] != "", not_found)) + found

print all_items
# all_items = ['amin0', 'an', 'di', 'meth', 'yl', 'eth', 'ol']
```

Assumption: Your final list does not require a particular order.